# Can't change AWS S3 content-type metadata using boto3 python

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm trying to change `Content-type` metadata for S3 object using boto3 library for python3 (as suggested in this SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39596988/1723695):

```py
s3 = session.resource('s3')
buck = s3.Bucket(BUCK_NAME)
obj = buck.Object('fe8e78d7-154f-4cd7-97a2-b432a67aabba')
obj.metadata.update({'Content-type': 'image/jpeg'})
obj.copy_from(CopySource={'Bucket': BUCK_NAME, 'Key': obj.key},
        Metadata=obj.metadata, MetadataDirective='REPLACE')
```

This code updates metadata for S3 object successfully, but 
`x-amz-meta-content-type` key instead of `Content-type` (see screenshot from AWS S3 object properties). Why this happens and how to update `Content-Type` metadata for S3 object using `boto3`?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```py
s3 = session.resource('s3')
buck = s3.Bucket(BUCK_NAME)
obj = buck.Object('fe8e78d7-154f-4cd7-97a2-b432a67aabba')
obj.copy_from(CopySource={'Bucket': BUCK_NAME, 'Key': obj.key},
        ContentType='image/jpeg', MetadataDirective='REPLACE')
```