# how to update metadata on an S3 object larger than 5GB?

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3

I am using the boto3 API to update the S3 metadata on an object.

I am making use of [How to update metadata of an existing object in AWS S3 using python boto3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39596987/how-to-update-metadata-of-an-existing-object-in-aws-s3-using-python-boto3)

My code looks like this:

```
    s3_object = s3.Object(bucket,key)
    new_metadata = {'foo':'bar'}
    s3_object.metadata.update(new_metadata)
    s3_object.copy_from(CopySource={'Bucket':bucket,'Key':key}, Metadata=s3_object.metadata, MetadataDirective='REPLACE')
```

This code fails when the object is larger than 5GB. I get this error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidRequest) when calling the CopyObject operation: The specified copy source is larger than the maximum allowable size for a copy source: 5368709120
```

How does one update the metadata on an object larger than 5GB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it myself but seems you can use [boto3.resource('s3').meta.client.copy](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/client/copy.html) method to overwrite the object and specify the metadata in `ExtraArgs` parameter. This method performs multipart upload so it's suitable for working with files larger than 5 GB.

**EDIT**:
I've just tried that and it works. The only thing to keep in mind is to add `MetadataDirective` parameter to `ExtraArgs` dictionary, otherwise you'll encounter the following error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidRequest) when calling the CopyObject operation: This copy request is illegal because it is trying to copy an object to itself without changing the object's metadata, storage class, website redirect location or encryption attributes.
```

Code example:

```
import boto3


s3_resource = boto3.resource("s3")

bucket, key = "your-bucket", "your-key"

copy_source = {"Bucket": bucket, "Key": key}

extra_args = {
    "ContentType": "text/csv",
    "MetadataDirective": "REPLACE",
}

s3_resource.meta.client.copy(copy_source, bucket, key, ExtraArgs=extra_args)
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to the size of your object, try invoking a multipart upload and use the copy_from argument. See the boto3 docs here for more information:

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.MultipartUploadPart.copy_from

Comment: But I'm not uploading the object...?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you can't just update the metadata - you need to re-copy the object to S3. You can copy it from s3 back to s3, but you can't just update, which is annoying for objects in the 100-500GB range.